# Setting ulimits without PAM

Tags: pam, ulimit

How to do that? Without PAM on my GNU/Linux OS the number of open files is 1024 by default and cannot be raised above 4096 (via `ulimit -n NNNN` command) despiting what is written in /etc/security/limits.conf. So, how does it work without PAM and how to set limits in such case?

===upd===

I decided for myself to use PAM. For those who wants to exceed the hard limit of opened files without PAM, look up for the `RLIMIT_NOFILE` constant in `include/asm-generic/resource.h` and `INR_OPEN_MAX` in `include/linux/fs.h` which defines the number of 4096 files as hard limit for rlimits. Check also CAP_SYS_RESOURCE which is required to be able to call `setrlimit()` on a running system to exceed the limit. It seems there is no way to do a system call like `setrlimit()` in bash, but it may be implemented as a binary executable file. Or you can make a kernel patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it can, you just need to run the syscall (which is what the `ulimit` command does) with CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.

There are two distinct values for every limit: hard and soft. Soft can be raised even by the user up to the hard limit. The hard limit can only be increased with proper privileges (for some resources it cannot be raised over kernel limit). See `man getrlimit` for more detailed information.

The easy way to do it is to run it by root (i.e. along the lines of: `su root; ulimit; su user` - first become root, from there change limits, and su back to the appropriate user), the secure way is to have a binary that would have just the aforementioned capability set (see `man setcap` and `man capabilities`) and proper access rights.

In your case, the hard limit is 4096, so you can't go beyond that on your own (as a user).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually I have 8192 as a soft limit and 16384 as hard. Look at my limits.conf: http://pastie.org/pastes/5424844/text Where can I read more about CAP_SYS_RESOURCE and how it is related to setting the number of opened files? I also can’t find manpages for getprlimit on my system, can you suggest a package name or something to search for? The program I want run cannot be started with root privilegies and as you may noticed, there is another user which rights the program is running with.

Comment: If I understood your hint correctly, there is a limit in the kernel, which is 4096 and is used when no PAM installed, so maybe there are some CONFIG_* options that may increase the limits?

Comment: @user685107 sorry, typo in the function name it is `getrlimit`, I have updated the answer.

`limits.conf` is only used by PAM, it has no effect otherwise.

Comment: @user685107 as for the 4096, I believe this is the default hard limit for number of open files. I'm successfully changing to 16k often with the `su - ulimit - su` idiom.